# How can I count the number of reverted edits of a Wikipedia user?

Tags: wikipedia

In the [German Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Wikipedia) you don't get some rights depending on the number of reverted edits you have. I would like to know how many of my edits were reverted.

I know http://toolserver.org/~guandalug/tools/stimmberechtigung.php?user=USERNAME, where you can check if you may vote.

I know http://toolserver.org/~soxred93/pcount/index.php?name=USERNAME&lang=de&wiki=wikipedia where you can see a very detailed log of your changes. Among others, you can see how many edits were deleted. Are deleted edits the same as reverted? Let's say you create a new article. For this article, you make 20 edits. Afterwards, the article gets deleted. Does your "revert count" go up by 20?

Comment: reverted edits mean that your edits were removed just after you made them and the old version is restored. I don't know any right you get based on reverted edits in the German Wikipedia (it doesn't matter whether your edits are still in the article or not). Deleted edits go up when you make an edit to an article that is deleted afterwards. Lost in translation amybe?

Comment: You get an "active sighter status" (see http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Gesichtete_Versionen#Sichterstatus)

Comment: It only talks about deleted edits. Reverted edits are not taken into account. As I already said deleted edits are edits on articles that will be deleted afterwards.

Comment: No, it also talks about reverted edits: "Maximal 5 Bearbeitungen des Benutzers wurden von Sichtern oder Administratoren zurückgesetzt." zurückgesetzt = reverted (gelöscht = deleted)

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen it, thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Is an English-language version of this page available?

Comment: [Wikipedia:Flagged revisions/Sighted versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Flagged_revisions/Sighted_versions#Sighted_versions)

Answer (score 1):

Of course WikiStats has this (for all languages). :) The top reverted/reverting users are at http://stats.wikimedia.org/EN/EditsRevertsDE.htm#table3
The full rankings should be somewhere in the huge CSV reports archives. https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikistats_csv They're updated rarely though and the format is a bit obscure (needs documentation at Meta-Wiki). Still great for digging!

However, as noted, I don't think this is a requirement for anything.